# Cannot save some SVG to JPG by pyvips

Tags: python, linux, svg, jpeg

I met an issue when I convert this SVG to image and I cannot workaround, does anyone know the possible reason?

Error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Cairo error "out of memory"', /build/librsvg-RSSQuy/librsvg-2.48.9/vendor/cairo-rs/src/enums.rs:274:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5
```

SVG URL: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Carreteras_de_Pamplona.svg

Code:

```
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(svg_name, memory=True, fail=True)
image.write_to_file(jpg_name)
```

Environments:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64G RAM)
- pyvips                 2.2.1
- libvips-dev/focal 8.9.1-2 amd64
- libvips-doc/focal 8.9.1-2 all
- libvips-tools/focal 8.9.1-2 amd64
- libvips42/focal,now 8.9.1-2 amd64 [installed]

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird SVG. If you look at the header, it has the ViewBox set to be:

```
   viewBox="-269795.54 4657840.8 1466.8124 1213.8088"
```

And it gives your librsvg terrible indigestion.

I tried with librsvg in ubuntu 22.04 and it seems to work, but you get a very screwy image:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips copy Carreteras_de_Pamplona.svg x.jpg
74176:0.28
```

So 74MB and 0.3s to make this:

[image]

A very tall, thin image, with your map as the tiny square at the bottom. If you zoom and crop, you can get some detail:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips crop Carreteras_de_Pamplona.svg[scale=90] x.png 0 29972 1010 836
91368:0.57
```

90MB and 0.6s to make:

[image]

You can't zoom it any further, unfortunately, because librsvg won't render an image with any axis over 32k pixels.

If possible, I would go back to the SVG source and regenerate the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an "out of memory" error, which is actually no surpise with that SVG, as it is pretty large. I suggest just downloading/saving that file to your pc and converting it to a PNG with something like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator.

If you want a solution to the problem itself: get more RAM, either through closing other programs or upgrading your hardware/doing it on another PC

Comment: I can't convert the image to PNG with this package. Is there a way to convert the image using only python without using a desktop program?

Comment: Or how can it raise the exception when I convert it to JPG? Not just crashed.

Comment: A carefully designed software should not crash when facing an out of memory condition. But many developers just ignore that, because they never encounter such errors when developing and testing their code...